# rails credentials apparently edited, but not accesisble

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A set of credentials were set and saved via this command:

```
$ EDITOR=vim bin/rails credentials:edit --environment development
File encrypted and saved.
```

If the editor is relaunched, the data is apparently saved coherently with the file's updated timestamp.

```
development:
  api_server_key: 'gibberish'
```

Yet when calling:

```
Rails.application.credentials.config
```

the only attribute returned is the

```
{:secret_key_base=>"lotsa_gibberish"}
```

How can the api_server_key be then accessed?

Comment: If you're using Rails 6 you don't want to nest your credentials in the `development` key.  That was done in Rails 5 as it only had a single file. Instead you use multiple files with credentials for each env.  https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/10/rails-6-adds-support-for-multi-environment-credentials.html

Comment: RIght, That is what I believe `EDITOR=vim bin/rails credentials:edit --environment development` accomplishes.  Simplifying the contents to `api_server_key: 'gibberish'` saves to `development.yml.enc` but I still cannot find a way to access the value in the console.  `Rails.application.credentials.api_server_key` returns `nil`

Comment: Right but with that Yaml you would have to use `Rails.application.credentials.development.config`. Thats not what you want.

Comment: That leads to `NoMethodError (undefined method `config' for nil:NilClass)`  as `Rails.application.credentials.development` does return `nil`

Comment: Found it.  `reload!` in the console does NOT work in this context.

Comment: `reload!` does not actually reinitialize the rails app. It just reloads all the autoloaded constants.